# mysql query that a user has a row for every experience id

Tags: mysql, sql, validation

I have a SQL problem. I have a table where a user gets a row for every experience they complete. The schema looks similar to this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d6a87/4

I am trying to write a query that lists every user that has expid 1-5. So in my example it would list userids: 1,2, and 4. Since userid 3 does not have 5 rows, one for each experience that user shouldn't be listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would like to use is "group by"
the query would look like it:

```
select userid
from some_table
group by userid
having count(*)>=5
```

you can also be creative and force 5 different expeids by

```
select userid
from some_table
group by userid
having count(distinct expid)>=5
```

light reading about group by:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Good luck!

Comment: condition should be equal or greater

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
SELECT * FROM some_table GROUP BY UserID having count(*)>= 5;
```

They way I see it should be like this but your question is not 100% clear, since you said 5 rows for every ExpID.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table GROUP BY UserID, ExpID having count(*)>= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,userid,expid FROM 
some_table 
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING count(*)>= 5
```

Result:

```
ID      USERID  EXPID
1       1       1
6       2       1
13      4       1
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d6a87/18).

You just need to add the `having` clause. Read more [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).